# Why are azure parquet files saved from Stream Analytics so big?

Tags: azure, parquet, azure-stream-analytics

I am running some tests using stream analytics to save parquet files to a blob store. When I try to use the parquet file type, the size of the files seem to be too big.

For example I have a file that is 153 KB in size when I download it from azure blob storage. Then when I read it using pandas and save it again as a parquet file (without any other processing done). It reduces to 17 KB.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_parquet('downloaded_from_azure.parquet') # has a size of 153 KB
df.to_parquet('pandas.parquet') # has a size of 17 KB
df.to_csv('pandas.csv') # 176 KB
```

So this seems to me that the parquet files saved by Azure Stream Analytics are 9 times bigger than when it is done with pandas. Is this a bug? Am I missing something? Is Microsoft trying to earn some extra money from their storage?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems due to file compression. Azure Stream Analytics doesn't support file compression for now so file size = raw data size + metadata size (header/footer/column and type definition etc). I suspect pandas library you used has compression turned on by default.

The main reason ASA didn't do this was to improve throughput for streaming jobs but we can certainly looking into surfacing file compression as a user configuration, e.g. gzip and snappy.

Comment: Why would anyone then use the parquet file type if no compression is used?

Comment: @Regnav  One would assume for the partition elimination when querying the files?